# Created a StickMan with the skin modifier but his shoulder acts weird in pose mode

Tags: modifiers, armature, bones

[image: stickman]

I was expecting his upper arm to stay straight but it seems to flex to try to satisfy the bend. How can I get it to straighten out?

Thanks!

Comment: it should be sufficient to edit bone weights, that I guess were automatically created by the "create armature" modifier button...

Comment: You need to adjust the weight painting, you can find a lot of tutorials on the subject on youtube.

Comment: Yes, thank you to you both! Because my mesh was so simple, the easiest thing to do was to restart the process from scratch. I think if there is a way to clear weights that would work or reweight them like Otto said.